# WPF has detected evidence that this app (or a component it uses) has changed the floating point control word

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

We at [Chem4Word](https://www.chem4word.co.uk) are developing a VSTO addin for Microsoft Word using Visual Studio 2022.

Occasionally we see the message below in the visual studio output window

"WPF has detected evidence that this app (or a component it uses) has changed the floating point control word. This is not supported in a .NET app.  Please ask the app (or component) author to fix it."

I have perfomed several google seraches to attempt to find out what this message means and how we should fix it.

Does word mean Microsoft Word?
If not what does the warning mean?

I have enabled as many breakpoints as I can do and still run our add in to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

That is not related to Word at all. This is a general math issue, I suppose related to the WPF UI in your add-in.

The floating-point control word enables the program to change the precision, rounding, and infinity modes in the floating-point math package.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I kind of thought that it might not be related to MS Word.

Do you have any idea how I might debug where the problem is?

Comment: I suppose the problem is not related to Word at all. Try reproducing it only with WPF on a problematic machine.